# template recursion when I use the non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I want to write a Matrix class. But when I want to handle the determinant function, I get into trouble. The error is the determinant(next).

```
template<typename T, int row, int column>
T determinant(const Mat<T, row, column>& current)
{
    if (row == 1) return current[0][0];
    if (row == 2) return current[0][0] * current[1][1] - current[0][1] * current[1][0];
    T sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= row - 1; i++)
    {
        T sign = 1;
        if (i % 2 == 1) sign = -sign;
        Mat<T, row -1, column - 1> next;
        for (int j = 0, nextRow = 0; j <= row - 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) continue;
            for (int k = 0; k <= row - 2; k++)
            {
                next[nextRow][k] = current[j][k + 1];
            }
            nextRow++;
        }
        sum += sign * current[i][0] * determinant(next);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? How do you call this code?

Comment: probably he reached compiler recursion limit. @user15839305 please provide [mcve] you may use [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nxP1Ed) for that.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce issue and depending on C++ you have different problems. Before C++17 you need partial specialization to do recursion in this case and only classes can do that. In case of C++17 you need `constexpr` keyword in respective places..

Comment: Unrelated: the way you calculate a determinant is very inefficient and will work only for rather small matrices.

Comment: In fact it is wrong implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be with the template recursion.  Nothing is stopping the compiler from creating invalid Matrix classes.  I don't think the compiler will evaluate the if statements at compile time.

```
Mat<T, 0, 0> next;
```

You might try a specialization of the matrix class.  This would stop the template recursion at compile time.

```
template<class T, unsigned int rows, unsigned int column>
Mat
{
   public:
   Det()
   {
      //Do recursion and decrement rows
   }
   protected:
   T Data[row][column];
}



template<class T, unsigned int column>
Mat<T,2,column>
{
   public:
   Det()
   {
      return Data[0][0] * Data[1][1] - Data[0][1] * Data[1][0];
   }
   protected:
   T Data[2][column];
}
```